# default ontologies loaded into Graphdb

Tags: ontology, graphdb

I am interested in finding out what are the ontologies preloaded into Graphdb by default. This will help me identify what ontologies (.ttl files) do I need to add along with my ontology as part of the package, especially in the situations when there is no Internet connection.

I know that some ontologies such as rdfs and owl are preloaded into GraphDb. but I could not find any list on preloaded ontologies.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that OWL does not differentiate very clearly ontology from instance triples. Also GraphDB introduces another term "axiomatic triple" (i.e. statement that cannot be deleted with a normal user transaction) used to separate the ontology statements from the normal RDF.

There are 3 ways of loading ontologies as axiomatic triples in GraphDB:

1. Ruleset - will import all statements from the beginning of a PIE file as axiomatic statements. Check [here](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/reasoning.html#axioms) for additional information.
2. Add imports initialisation parameter - this will safe a configuration predicate in the SYSTEM's repository See the [configuration parameter](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/configuring-a-repository.html#configuring-a-repository-configuration-parameters-imports)
3. Add a special predicate in the beginning of an RDF file - the system transaction will add all following statements as ontology. Check [here](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/delete-optimisations.html#schema-transactions).

Another approach is to add every file in a different named graph. This will allow you to see which graphs are currently stored in the repository.

Comment: Thanks. I understand all the options to load additional ontologies. Does it mean that there are no other preloaded frameworks or ontologies (other than rdf or owl as mentioned in the rulesets) in Graphdb? If I want to load dublin core, skos or other ontologies and use their axioms, I have to find all the dependencies and load them separately?

Comment: The level of OWL, RDF and RDFS semantics is meta-model. SKOS and Dublin Core adopts their semantics to describe concrete information models. All instances are your data.